# Is there a complex date filter algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, date, filter

Essentially, I want a system that can filter simply such as "Between August 4th and August 7th", but be as complicated as "Every third saturday or monday of each january on leap years".

I figured that in order to represent the complicated boolean algebra, I would need a tree structure.  Each node would either be a boolean operation (AND, OR, XOR, NOT) and then would have children that it apply to, which can either be specific filters or another boolean operation.

Each "specific filter" would be something like "Sundays" or "Leap Years".  I think everything up to this point is very doable.  However, the problem then arises in parsing the tree to actually find what dates are needed, in order to then make database queries to get the data points.

With the example above (Every third saturday or monday of each january on leap years), if we pre-restrict ourselves to the years that we have data (5 years worth).  If the sat/mon filters happen to be the top nodes in the tree, we will end up with 500 segmented dates (2 per week, 50 weeks a year, 5 years).  Then, the next node has to search through all 500 to find which ones conform to "every third" filter.  This isn't even the most complicated example, because an arbitrary number of filters should be allowed, and XOR makes that even more crazy.

So, is there any easy route?  Did someone already build this?  This is just a small part a project involving data visualization, but it seems that it could be an entire project by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [couple](http://www.rubyinside.com/3-new-date-and-time-libraries-for-rubyists-3238.html) in Ruby. [IceCube](http://seejohnrun.github.com/ice_cube/) seems promising, even though it might not support all your needs.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great, and gives me a good direction to go in.